# how to register a web service in iis?

Tags: c#, web-services, iis

I have a web service made in c# and I want to know how to register it in IIS for consumption from another app. I know how to consume it from the same solution but this isn't the same case. Searching the internet, I've only found how to register an app.

Comment: Can you post what is the error you get. When you have published the web service on IIS can you browse the web service using IE. Can you give some sample code on how your web service looks i.e. it is WCF Service or old web service(asmx) or REST service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web service is treated like any other website in IIS. Simply convert the site to an application and pick the appropriate .Net framework version.

Comment: @BlaShadow - this is the correct answer.  Is your website set up correctly?  Are there any other html / aspx files next to your web service?

Comment: @BlaShadow What happened when it "did not work" did it throw an exception, return a 404 response or did the server explode in a giant mushroom cloud?

Comment: @BenRobinson yeah return a 404 response and the files are correctly

Comment: @BlaShadow, are specifying a full path? For example, are you trying to access the service by going to `http://foo.com` or by going to `http://foo.com/MyService.asmx`?

The latter is correct, assuming you haven't set `MyService.asmx` to be the default document.

Comment: @JamesHill is in local. but I specified the full path I the same IIS return me HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error :S

Comment: Thanks I Solve the problem I put on iis directory browsing enable and worked!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

After you have setup the website for web service you need to do some setting in your web.config. I guess you might be missing them

Add service to the web.config like following

```
<services>
  <service name="RestService.RestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestService.IRestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="web">         
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
```

Also add service behaviour and endpoint behaviour

```
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```